# Caching with Sliding Expiration in ASP.NET Page Methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, caching, pagemethods

I know that when declaring a page method in ASP.NET, I can specify a `CacheDuration` like so:

```
[WebMethod(CacheDuration=60)]
public static void Foo()
{
    //TODO Bar
}
```

But from what I understand, `CacheDuration` only supports absolute expiration. I want to have *sliding expiration*. So that leads me to believe that I need to access the `System.Web.Caching.Cache` object somehow. But, since page methods are static, and this is essentially a standalone web service, I'm not sure how to access it statically. The only ways I have seen on Google rely on getting it from the `HttpContext`. But, there is no `HttpContext` available to me here, right?

Or, do I need to use the `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache` to do my own caching?

Much thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can access

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache
```

from your page method.